# Save username and password for auto connection to firebase react-native redux application

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I'm building a React-native / Redux-thunk / Firebase app for IOS. Here is a part of my app.js.

```
  {
    this.props.data.userConnected==false?
    <View style={styles.container1}>
    <Login/>
    </View>

  :null
  }
  {
    this.props.data.userConnected==true?
    <View style={styles.container1}>
    <Connected/>
    </View>
  :null
  }
```

When a user click on login, i'm using the firebase.auth function, and if connection succeed, i'm setting the variable userConnected to true in the redux store. My problem is that after something like 3 hours, my users are being disconnected and the variable userConnected is getting set to false as it is the initial value.

I dont really know what to do because i was thinking the redux store can't be initialize again unless the app is being closed and reopened.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your session token and refresh token returned from firebase and add it to redux-persist. Every single time app goes to background you can check and reopened again you need to check if session token expired. If it is use refresh token to regenerate and save returned values again. For more information please have a look at [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using react-native-local-storage.

First I import the pacquage with :

```
import ls from 'react-native-local-storage';
```

When user first login, after passing the firebase.auth(email,password), im writing into the local storage of the iphone with:

```
        ls.save('email', email)
        .then(() => {
          ls.get('email').then((data) => {console.log("get: ", data)});
          // output should be "get: Kobe Bryant"
        })


       ls.save('password', password)
        .then(() => {
          ls.get('password').then((data) => {console.log("get: ", data)});
          // output should be "get: Kobe Bryant"
        })
```

Then, when in the componentWillMount function of my app component, i'm getting the email and password of the user with:

```
   ls.get('email').then((email) => {
     if (email!=null){
        ls.get('password').then((password) => {
          console.log("password: ", password);
          console.log("email: ", email);
          this.props.initApp(3,email,'');
          this.props.initApp(4,'',password);
          this.props.initApp(1,email,password,this.props.data);
        });
      }
    });
```

After getting the data, i'm calling my redux action which call firebase.auth(email,password). And here we are, just set an automatic login to my react native firebase app :).